# Insert new row under a specific text using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert new row under a particular text(selected from userform) with the new text but getting an error "Object variable or With block variable not set" in the line `"fvalue.Value = Me.txtremark.Value"`.

Please help me to find where exactly the mistake I did in the Code. I was trying to find many ways but failed.

**Excel Table:**

[image]

Required Output:

[image]

```
Private Sub cmdadd_Click()

    Dim fvalue As Range
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    wks.Activate
    Set fvalue = wks.Range("B:B").Find(What:=Me.txtremark.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    fvalue.Value = Me.txtremark.Value
    fvalue.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    fvalue.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.txtplace.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see the code line you are referring to

Comment: Oh sorry....this is the line "fvalue.Value = Me.txtremark.Value"

Comment: What kind of object is `txtremark`?

Comment: It is a TextBox in the userform

Comment: For the new value(Ter), i have a separate TextBox in my userform from which the newly inserted row gets populated.

Comment: Similar question is asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097786/vba-populate-userform-data-by-insert-rows-in-between-cells-based-on-the-matching Have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Position As Range, rngToSearch As Range
    Dim strToFound As String

    'Change strToFound value
    strToFound = "Test"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rngToSearch = .Range("B:B")

        Set Position = rngToSearch.Find(strToFound, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not Position Is Nothing Then

            Debug.Print Position.Row
            .Rows(Position.Row).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert

        End If


    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The above Code works only when i give a particular value in "strToFound" but I need to call this value from the Userform TextBox (txtremark).

Comment: See the comment above this line of code - `'Change strToFound value`. This means that you have o change the code to get the value you want

Comment: Yes... I did  for example i have given as strToFound = "Sam" then it runs not a Problem. But my requirement is when i give "strToFound = Me.txtremark.Value" the Code is not able to read.

Comment: `strToFound` is declare as string so it can takes anything which is string.

Comment: ok.. and is this the correct way to add new TextBox value from the userform..                                                                                                          Position.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.txtplace.Value

Comment: yes, if you want to add in the new row the value from txtplace

Comment: can you please suggest how to replace strToFound = "Sam" with strToFound = Me.txtremark.Value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197387/discussion-between-error-1004-and-sant).

Answer (score 1):

Try using a separate variable to pass values to the worksheet, or just refer to the textbox.

Additionally, activating (and selecting) is not necessary and will hurt your macro's speed and is prone to errors.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdadd_Click()

    Dim fvalue As Range
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set fvalue = wks.Range("B:B").Find(What:=Me.txtremark.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not fvalue Is Nothing Then
        wks.Rows(fvalue.Row + 1).EntireRow.Insert
        wks.Cells(fvalue.Row + 1, fvalue.Column + 1).Value = Me.txtremark.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

I have taken the liberty to check if the value is found in the first place

Comment: I tried with your Code but the new row is added above the "Find" value (Example: Sam is in row 4 and when i run the Code the new row is added above row 4)

Comment: Fixed the issue @sant

Comment: Yes.. it worked and the correct way to populate the TextBox value in the new row i.e. below Sam from the userform..                                                             wks.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.txtplace.Value

Comment: I can't understand what you're saying... Did my code work for you? If so, you can accept it by clicking the check mark just below the downvote button

Comment: Code worked to insert new row.... but how to populate the userform values into the new row

Comment: It should do that with `wks.Cells(fvalue.Row + 1, fvalue.Column + 1).Value = Me.txtremark.Value`

Comment: Yes.. now the Code works perfectly as required. Thanks alot.

Comment: Glad to have helped!